# Liquid If Variant statement

Tags: shopify, liquid

I'm trying to run a piece of code depending on whether a product is a variant or not. For example:

```
{% if product is a variant %}
  DO THIS
{% else %}
  DO THIS INSTEAD
{% endif %}
```

Any ideas? Or is this just not possible?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this:

```
using {% if product.variants.size <= 1 %}
```